# How to display values from 3 fields from different tables into one column?

Tags: php, sql

I would like to combine a field from three different tables that has the same type of result. 
For example:

**Table: 1**

- Column: a.country_name
- Possible Values: United States, Canada, Germany

**Table: 2**

- Column: b.country_name
- Possible Values: Armenia, Poland, Turkey

**Table: 3**

- Column: c.country_name
- Possible Values: Portugal, Japan, Argentina

I am not having a problem joining these tables together (with a general 'countries' table linking each of these three with a country_id field). What I am having an issue with is I don't know how to combine these into 1 column.

I have tried doing:
COALESCE(a.country_name, b.country_name, c.country_name)

But this does not include all the possible values. Lets say a.country_name would return a result set of 4 countries, but b and c return 2. Only 2 would show when I would like all 4.

I would just like one column, that returns all of the possible values (they are all countries)
Such as:

**Country**

- United States
- Canada
- Germany
- Armenia
- Poland
- Turkey
- Portugal
- Japan
- Argentina

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is UNION:

```
SELECT a.country_name as country_name
from a
UNION
SELECT b.country_name as country_name
from b
SELECT c.country_name as country_name
from c;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I think you want UNION / UNION ALL.

```
SELECT country_name FROM a
UNION ALL
SELECT country_name FROM b
UNION ALL
SELECT country_name FROM c
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for `GROUP BY 'country_name'`. [More information on W3.](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

Comment: That would be nice but the issue is country_name is ambiguous because it is the same field name for the three tables.

Comment: Just a question. Why are you using 3 tables for same data?

Comment: Well I'm being sort of vague because it's a thing at work but there are three different tables that have a bunch of other fields specific to them, but country_id is common to each of them along with a general "Countries" table that has more info. I am trying to write a report that makes a count of how many people in each of those 3 separate tables are in that country for a given time.